# Determining the number of trinities in a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, mathematica

Based on the following adjacency matrix and the formula trace(A³)/6:

[image]

How can I use Mathematica to determine the number of trinitys? (also known as triangles or 3-cliques)

Comment: you just use mathematica to evaluate the expression

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command does the job:

```
Trace[MatrixPower[A,3]]/6
```

Comment: Can you explain why the denominator is $6$?  I would have said $2$, because we can go around the cycle in $2$ ways.

Comment: @saulspatz because there are three possible starting vertices

Comment: @Jorge Oh duh.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah right, I see what I forgot, I was trying commands such as trace(A^3)/6 and Tr(A^3)/6. Thank you :)

Comment: I ended up getting an answer of 436 :)